# Regex backreference why not working

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

I have the regex `((\w;)+\w\n)(-{3,}\n)((\w;)+\w\n)+` which is suposed to match the following text:

```
H;e;l;a;a
---------
J;a;c;k;p
```

[as can be seen here](https://regex101.com/r/6z61m0/1).

I noticed that in my regex I have a repeating part of `((\w;)+\w\n)` so I tried to refactor my regex using back references.

So I got `((\w;)+\w\n)(-{3,}\n)\1+` but this one does not match the above example text. Why is this backreference is not working?

Comment: Which language or tool are you using this in? Also backreferences are for referring to the previously matched text, not regex itself

Comment: In some regexes, you need to mask the + sign. Others operate on complete lines and won't match a newline.

Comment: I am using the regex in Java but am first testing the regex in regexr.com

Comment: @Vasan how can I get the backreference to match the previous regex?

Comment: Or is there any other way to remove the duplication in my initial regex?

Comment: Short answer: No. What you're looking for is called a regex subroutine, and isn't supported in Java. You'll need to use plain old variables to avoid duplication while building the pattern.

Comment: would it work in kotlin? @vasan

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what kotlin is. If it supports PCRE standards, it might. Try this in regexr.com after selecting PCRE from the dropdown: `((\w;)+\w[\r\n]*)(-{3,}[\r\n]*)(?1)+`

Comment: I just checked the documentation for kotlin. If [this](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/-regex/index.html) is the correct class, you're out of luck - they're just referring to Java's documentation for syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
((\w;)+\w)\n-{3,}\n((?1)\n)+(?1)
```

This seems work for this case and following text in the PCRE.

[sample text]

```
H;e;l;a;a
---------
J;a;c;k;p
c;d;e;d;c
f;d;e;c;d
k;d;c;d;s
d;e;f;d;e
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LCxVPB/15)

If the sample text ends in new line(\n), then last part in this regex **(?1)** is not needed

Comment: As mentioned in comments, this is PCRE syntax and not supported in Java or Kotlin (which OP expects).

Comment: I missed some comments. Sorry, I edited it already with the phrase this regex is apllicable for PCRE:-)